# Knitr - Define Latex commands that call R functions using Sexpr

Tags: r, function, command, latex, knitr

I'm basically wondering how to define a new Latex command such that it allows the nesting of Sexpr and some other R function, where the Latex argument is an R object.

As fortunute happenstance, the idea somewhat is transmitted by the new command structure given below:

```
 \newcommand{\SomeLatexCommand}[1]{\Sexpr{"#1"}}
```

Where fortunately the argument is indeed shown, albeit in string. With this in mind, I was hoping upon the following command:

```
\newcommand{\SweetLatexCommand}[1]{\Sexpr{SomeRFunction(get("#1"))}}
```

However, once inside nested inside an R function, `#1` is not read as a placeholder for the Latex argument, but instead as an existing R variable.

Is there a way to make the last comand work? Or else, are there also other neat ways to define Latex commands which in turn can call on any R function through R objects?

Good day,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that.  The problem is the way `knitr` works:

R runs the `knit()` function (or some other `knitr` function).  That function looks through the source for code chunks and `\Sexpr` calls, executes them, and replaces them with the requested output, producing a `.tex` file.

Then LaTeX processes that `.tex` file.  R is no longer involved.

Since `\newcommand` is a LaTeX command, it is only handled in the final stage, after all R evaluation is done.

There may be a way in `knitr` to specify another "macro" that works the way `\Sexpr` works, but I don't think there's a way to have several of them.

So what you should do is write multiple functions in R, and call those to do what you want, as `\Sexpr{fn1(...)}`, `\Sexpr{fn2(...)}`, etc.

I suppose if you were really determined, you could add an extra preprocessor stage at the beginning, that went through your `Rnw` file and replaced all strings that looked like `\SweetLatexCommand{blah}` with `\Sexpr{SomeRFunction(get("blah"))}` and then called `knit()`, but that seems like way too much work.

Comment: It's nice to know how Sexpr out. I wonder, though, why defining such a function as ``\newcommand{\SomeLatexCommand}[1]{\Sexpr{"#1"}}`` does work. Instead of always printing #1 everytime one writes \SomeLatexCommand{Some text}, on the pdf file we do get the input as a string in "Some text". How can this happen if \Sexpr should have replaced the "#1" output in on the tex file? Ah, I guess because putting back the #1 will make the newcommand definition exactly as expected. Am I wrong?

Comment: As a side note, yeah, I like the idea of using a list of fixed latex functions of fixed R function outputs. I supposse this merits another thread, but do you believe it fixable a solution such as ``\Sexpr`` only calls R functions only if ``\Sexpr`` is found _after_ ``\begin{document}``?